# Não consigo visualizar a maioria das questões e posta da comunidade pelo app!

Tags: bug, android-app

Estou usando o Stack Exchange APP e não consigo visualizar quase nenhuma questão ou resposta. O conteúdo fixa em branco!

[image]

Comment: A sua pergunta foi fechada no [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)? Pode deixar um link para ela?

Comment: Cross-post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286210/229289